# ¿Cómo convertir 'N' número de filas a columnas?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema,tengo una tabla donde registro varias acciones, pero esas acciones las guardo en un solo campo separadas por una coma, ya logre separar ese campo en filas con `string_split`, ahora lo que quiero es convertir cada una de esas acciones en columnas y que al momento de mostrarlas en columnas me muestre como valor un 'X', algo asi:

Tabla Original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como quiero que se muestre:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo que no todos los registros tienen las mismas acciones unos tienen mas otros menos, por favor les pido su ayuda, gracias.

La consulta que he intentado es la siguiente:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(MAX);
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SET @columns = (select vAcciones from cTurnoTmp tmp where nIdTurnoTmp = 1 )

set @sql =
 'Select '+@columns+'
 from (
    SELECT value as accion, ''X'' as temp FROM cTurnoTmp CROSS APPLY string_split(vAcciones, '','') where nIdTurnoTmp = 1
 )as pivote1
 PIVOT
 (
    max(temp)
    for accion in ('+@columns+')
 ) as pivote'

execute (@sql)
```

Y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solamente en el primero me sale 'X' y todos los de mas en null, pero yo quiero que en todos me salga 'X'.

Comment: Interesante. Muéstranos la consulta que has intentado, y lo que has obtenido.

Comment: SELECT value FROM cTurnoTmp tm CROSS APPLY string_split(tm.vAcciones, ',') where tm.nIdTurnoTmp = 1 y solamente he obtenido los siguientes datos:

VALUE
Contestar
Atender
Revisar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás bastante cerca con tu consulta:

```
/*Creación de la tabla*/
CREATE TABLE dbo.Tabla(Id int, Acciones varchar(100));

/*Inserción de datos*/
INSERT INTO dbo.Tabla
SELECT 1,'Contestar,Atender,Revisar'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'Atender,Imprimir,Responder'
;

/*Comienzo Query Resultados*/
DECLARE @columnsSelect nvarchar(MAX), @columns nvarchar(MAX), @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT  @columnsSelect = STRING_AGG('ISNULL('+QUOTENAME(x.value)+',''0'') AS ' + QUOTENAME(x.value) + '',','),
        @columns       = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(x.value),',') 
FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT a.value
        FROM dbo.Tabla t
        OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.Acciones,',') a
     ) x
;


SET @sql = '
SELECT Id, ' + @columnsSelect + ' 
FROM (  SELECT Id, value Accion, ''X'' Temp 
        FROM dbo.Tabla
        OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Acciones, '','')) pivote1 
PIVOT ( MAX(temp) FOR Accion IN ('+@columns+') ) pivote'
;

EXECUTE(@sql);
```

Los resultados son los siguientes:

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ Id ║ Atender ║ Contestar ║ Imprimir ║ Responder ║ Revisar ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║  1 ║ X       ║ X         ║ 0        ║ 0         ║ X       ║
║  2 ║ X       ║ 0         ║ X        ║ X         ║ 0       ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Y [acá hay un fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4e3f8969d2683dfe20a71214c2bd3785) para que lo veas en acción.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, pero el problema esta en que quiero cambiar todos los NULL por algun otro carácter ya sea 1 o 0

Comment: @AxelRangel ok, actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: @AxelRangel si esta respuesta de Lamak te ha solucionado tu problema, recuerda marcarla como respuesta aceptada, por favor (y si quieres, dale voto arriba también).